# How to remove the `ListViewSubItem` form PDF generated from `ListView`?

Tags: c#, itext

When exporting my `ListView` to PDF it then displays the correct information but adds `ListViewSubItems` infront of the information in each column

This is the code I am currently using:

```
private void tsbSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("c:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\TestDocument.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();

        iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(lvwAttributes.Columns.Count);
        PdfPRow row = null;
        float[] columnWidths = new float[] { 10f, 20f, 30f, 10f, 10f, 10f };
        table.SetWidths(columnWidths);

        table.WidthPercentage = 100;
        int iCol = 0;
        string colname = "";
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Products"));

        cell.Colspan = lvwAttributes.Columns.Count;

        foreach (ListViewItem item in lvwAttributes.Items)
        {
            if (lvwAttributes.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(item.SubItems[0].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(item.SubItems[1].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(item.SubItems[2].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(item.SubItems[3].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(item.SubItems[4].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(item.SubItems[5].ToString(), font5));
            }
        }
        document.Add(table);
        document.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("PDF CREATED!!");
    }
```

I would like it to display the Column Name and then the information correctly.

For Example at the moment I am getting

```
 |ListViewSubItem{Administrator} | ListViewSubItem{Full Access} | etc
```

I would like for it to display as

```
 |Administrator | Full Access |
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this, to get the text behind the `Sub Item`.

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lvwAttributes.Items)
    {
        if (lvwAttributes.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(item.SubItems[0].Text.ToString(), font5));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(item.SubItems[1].Text.ToString(), font5));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(item.SubItems[2].Text.ToString(), font5));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(item.SubItems[3].Text.ToString(), font5));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(item.SubItems[4].Text.ToString(), font5));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(item.SubItems[5].Text.ToString(), font5));
        }
    }
```